# It is possible to find position of parameters in same cell and replace/multiple in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets, vba

I really have a hard time to know how to express the result I want but I'll show you an example.

I'm using google sheets.
I have cells that contain multiple parameters.
For example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WpQZ.png)

So I want to do this:
If its find one of the variables in "Item Name" in "Item Number" It will replace it with his match price and then multiply by the quantity but in the order of the positions of each parameter.

```
For example:
1st CELL: =PINK(should be $10)*1+Red(should be $12)*4+Blue(should be $46)*3
2nd CELL: =12*3+10*5 [FINAL REASULT]
```

I hope it is understandable... Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But a VBA solution might be easier for you to implement. I suggest you familiarize with how this site works by taking the [Two Minute Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Then read the HELP pages for information as to [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hey! Thank you for providing me with these links, I'm new here.
I will edit it to be more clear.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you might want to investigate a VBA solution.
For Sheets, I came up with this formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(T(IF(1,TRIM(MID((SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""),",",REPT(" ",99))),IF(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))=1,1,(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))-1)*99),99)))),PriceTbl,2,0)*TRIM(MID((SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2," ",""),",",REPT(" ",99))),IF(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))=1,1,(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))-1)*99),99))),0,VLOOKUP(T(IF(1,TRIM(MID((SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""),",",REPT(" ",99))),IF(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))=1,1,(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))-1)*99),99)))),PriceTbl,2,0)*TRIM(MID((SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2," ",""),",",REPT(" ",99))),IF(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))=1,1,(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))-1)*99),99)))))
```

[image]

I am not all that familiar with Sheets, but the formula could be shortened slightly if Sheets allows named formulas, as does Excel.

In Excel, the formula would be an array formula (entered with ctrl+shift+enter):

```
=SUM(IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(T(IF(1,TRIM(MID((SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A7," ",""),",",REPT(" ",99))),seq_99,99)))),PriceTbl,2,0)*TRIM(MID((SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B7," ",""),",",REPT(" ",99))),seq_99,99))),0,VLOOKUP(T(IF(1,TRIM(MID((SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A7," ",""),",",REPT(" ",99))),seq_99,99)))),PriceTbl,2,0)*TRIM(MID((SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B7," ",""),",",REPT(" ",99))),seq_99,99))))
```

where

```
seq_99 refers to:  =IF(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))=1,1,(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))-1)*99)
```

And, easier to maintain, in my opinion, is a VBA solution:

```
Option Explicit
Function totalPrice(Items As String, Quantity As String, PriceTbl As Range) As Currency
    Dim vI, vQ
    Dim vPriceTbl
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    Dim Price As Currency


vI = Split(Items, ",")
vQ = Split(Quantity, ",")

'if the price table is lengthy, using a dictionary to store the amounts
'  with the key being the "color", would be much more efficient than
'  looping to find the correct price
vPriceTbl = PriceTbl

For I = 0 To UBound(vI)
    For J = 1 To UBound(vPriceTbl, 1)
        If Trim(vI(I)) = vPriceTbl(J, 1) Then
            Price = Price + vQ(I) * vPriceTbl(J, 2)
        End If
    Next J
Next I

totalPrice = Price

End Function
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you very much for the comment.
I tried to put that formula on google sheets and it shows an error.
https://ibb.co/mtRfi7

However, I don't know exactly what the VBA code exactly mean and how to use it on Google Sheets. 

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: And exactly what have you done to troubleshoot your error?  The screenshot I show is from Sheets, so it clearly works there.  You will have to determine what you did incorrectly.  But I would start with the obvious and examine the syntax of VLOOKUP and exactly what range you are referring to.

Comment: I added the VBA code because you included the `excel-vba` tag in your question.  If you don't know what it means, you will not be able to apply it to Sheets which does not use `excel-vba`.  If you want to learn about excel-vba, I suggest an internet search for learning materials.